# Getting Solr to provide spelling suggestions for "correctly" spelled words

Tags: solr

Let's say we have two words with easily confused spellings.  Let's say we take the terms:

derailer (a device used to prevent fouling of a rail track)

vs.

Derailleur (a device used for changing gear ratios on a bicycle)

Now for some reason we have both terms in our spelling suggestions.  As a result a search for one or the other will never yield spelling suggestions, despite it being likely that you'll get poor (or no) results if you meant the other term.

So the question is how can I convince solr to give me spelling suggestions if you search for one or the other, and what controls do I have to ensure that not every search results in showing spelling suggestions?

Comment: This particular problem (that is, dealing with homophones) would probably be better solved with a phonetic search, like [metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) (see Solr's [PhoneticFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PhoneticFilterFactory)).

Comment: Possibly, but in my case it can also be two similarly spelled words that are note homophones.  In fact my example isn't even in the same domain, it was just what I could think of after my example actually turned out to be an actual spelling error.